# Deshabilitar las actualizaciones de WordPress y Plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

Quisiera poder deshabilitar las actualizaciones de WordPress y Plugins a través de código para que ni el propio admin de wordprees lo pueda hacer.

Solo cuando el desarrollador web lo permita.

Estas lineas me sirven?

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );

define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Comment: Puedes usar [Easy Updates Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/) o bien  [Disable All WordPress Updates](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/) aunque sería bueno que seas consciente de las posibles consecuencias de un WP no actualizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con las siguientes líneas en el wp-config.php deshabilitas:

**TODO:**

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

**Plugins solamente:**

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

**Temas solamente**

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Lamentablemente WP es un framework altamente atacado. En mi UTM la mayoría de los ataques recibidos son hacia WordPress y van desde ataques al login hasta cualquier plugin mal programado.
Mi recomendación es siempre mantener tu WP actualizado porque en cada actualización liberan parches de seguridad importantes.

Comment: Creo que es importante marcar que `add_filter` no se debe añadir a `wp-config.php`...